# Configure cache prefix for database.defaultMetedataCache in ini config in Zend1

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework, configuration

I have configured in .ini file in Zend Framework 1 cache. It uses redis but i think it is not important. In the same ini file i have configuration forn saving in cache db_table metadata:

```
resources.db.defaultMetadataCache = rediscache
```

Problem is that I want to use different cache_id_prefix only for that data. I can copy all lines of cache configuration with different name but looking for better solution. Maybe there is an option for one-liner

```
resources.cachemanager.redisdbcache.parent = resources.cachemanager.rediscache
resources.cachemanager.redisdbcache.frontend.options.cache_id_prefix = dbcache_
```

Any ideas?